# Matching arrays in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-nested

I have document as below:

```
{
    "_index": "abc_local",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "1",
    "_version": 5,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "firstname": "simer",
        "lastname": "kaur",
        "gender": "1",
        "Address": "Punjab House Fed. Housing Society, Amritsar, Punjab, India",
        "email": "rav@yopmail.com",
        "occupation": "Php Developer",
        "work": "Development",
        "fav_hunting_land": 2,
        "zipcode": "",
        "marital_status": "1",
        "phone": "1234567899",
        "school": "sdfergdfh",
        "species": [{
            "id": 1
        }, {
            "id": 2
        }, {
            "id": 3
        }, {
            "id": 4
        }, {
            "id": 5
        }, {
            "id": 6
        }],
        "activities": [{
            "id": 1
        }],
        "fav_weapon": 6,
        "weapons": [{
            "id": 1
        }, {
            "id": 2
        }, {
            "id": 3
        }, {
            "id": 6
        }],
        "properties": [{
            "id": 4
        }]
    }
}
```

and I need to match user on basis of weapons and I am trying something like:

```
$params = [
            'index' => Constants::INDEX,
            'type' => Constants::DOC_TYPE_USERS,
            'body' => [
                "query"=> [
                    "bool"=> [
                        "must"=>   [ "match"=> [ "weapons.id"=>$params['weapons'] ]],

                        "should"=> [
                                    [ "match"=> [ "firstname"=> $params['search_text'] ]],
                                    [ "match"=> [ "lastname"=> $params['search_text']   ]]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                            ]
                        ]

                ];
```

as I am using elastic in PHP. Here $params['weapons'] is:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
```

I get an error:

> illegal_state_exception: Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:36

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated that how I can match array. I took reference from [nested datatypes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/nested.html)

**Update#1**:
parameters I am sending to my function: `{"from":0,"size":null,"city":null,"state":"0","weapons":["1","2"],"activities":[],"species":[],"properties":[],"search_text":"lastname"}`

**update#2**:
Body of my query in json format:

```
{
    "index": "abc_local",
    "type": "users",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match": {
                        "weapons.id": ["1", "2"]
                    }
                },
                "should": [{
                    "match": {
                        "firstname": "simer"
                    }
                }, {
                    "match": {
                        "lastname": "simer"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Construct the first `match` query the same way as the second and third ones. You have one too many array in there.

Comment: @Val Updated. Now I am getting exception: illegal_state_exception: Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:36

Comment: Now you're missing a `]` to end your array. Make sure the square brackets are balanced.

Comment: @Val It is balanced now. I reverted my changes.

Comment: it's still wrong: it needs to be like this: `[ "match"=> [ "weapons.id"=>$params['weapons'] ]]`

Comment: @Val thanks. I have updated my question.

Comment: What's your error now?

Comment: @Val as mentioned in my question : illegal_state_exception: Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:36

Comment: Can you `json_encode` your `$params` query it'll be easier to debug it in JSON with the substituted values.

Comment: @Val: {"from":0,"size":null,"city":null,"state":"0","weapons":["1","2"],"activities":[],"species":[],"properties":[],"search_text":"lastname"}

Comment: No, I'm asking for the body of the query, not the parameters to your function, i.e. what you have in `$params` in your question.

Comment: @Val I have made a 2nd update. My query would look something like that in json format but it would contain 'should' clause as well where I will match firstname and second name.

Comment: Please add `print_r(json_encode($params))` at the end of your code and show us your complete JSON.

Comment: @Val I have update update#2 Please check.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply replace the first `match` query by a `terms` one as `match` doesn't work with arrays of values.

```
 $params = [
        'index' => Constants::INDEX,
        'type' => Constants::DOC_TYPE_USERS,
        'body' => [
            "query"=> [
                "bool"=> [
                    "must"=>   [ "terms"=> [ "weapons.id"=>$params['weapons'] ]],
                                    ^
                                    |
                               change this

                    "should"=> [
                                [ "match"=> [ "firstname"=> $params['search_text'] ]],
                                [ "match"=> [ "lastname"=> $params['search_text']   ]]
                                    ]
                                ]
                        ]
                    ]

            ];
```

Comment: Awesome, glad we figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to check if any value from array matches to field from index then you have to "terms" instead of match.

```
{
    "index": "abc_local",
    "type": "users",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "terms": {
                        "weapons.id": ["1", "2"]
                    }
                },
                "should": [{
                    "match": {
                        "firstname": "simer"
                    }
                }, {
                    "match": {
                        "lastname": "simer"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

refer "Terms Level Query" in ElasticSearch docs.